# Creation of graphic element in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a question on Wordpress and elementor.
I tried to create a grapic element like this but i don't know if its possible to do this.
This element gonna go on every page (the rectangle).
If anyone has an idea to create this I am a taker.
Thank you in advance

[graphic element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZShXe.png)

Comment: Only with elementor or you can create this with css?

Comment: With elementor or css.
I take the best solution ahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution that may fits your needs:

```css
.element-wrapper{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position:relative;
}


.element-wrapper .text{
  background-color:tomato;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
  padding:10px;
  width:60%;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.element-wrapper .text:after{
  content:'';
  display:block;
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#fff;
  right:-10px;
  top:-10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.element-wrapper .text span{
  display:block;
  
}

.element-wrapper .line{
  background-color:tomato;
  height:1px;
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  z-index:1;
}

.element-wrapper .face-wrapper{
  position: relative;
  z-index:1;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding:20px;
}

.element-wrapper .face{
  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/02/19/15/34/orange-1210522_960_720.png");
  background-size:cover;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="element-wrapper">

  <div class="text">
    <span class="title">Defile de cosplay</span>
    <span class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
  </div>
  <div class="line">
  </div>
  <div class="face-wrapper">
    <div class="face">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna tried to integrate it in my website !